# Gatsby Starter Blog create page with form

Tags: gatsby, blogs

Is it possible to make a form or something similar so that people can create a post (with the extension .mdk) "dynamically" and not that the programmer has to do it from the code?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a CMS (Content management system) that addresses these very issues so that marketers and writers can create posts and blogs and developers can develop the look and feel of the pages.

A view to try out that have free versions that I have used are
[Contentful](https://www.contentful.com/)
[ButterCMS](https://buttercms.com/subscribe/#)

and a plethora of others.